# How do I handle error message in my case

Tags: php, error-handling

I am trying to catch an error with php when I connect to DB

I have something like

```
 try{
     //connect to DB    
 }catch(exception $e){
      echo $e
 }

 //other php codes...


 //My html elements...
  <div>....
```

My problem is that I want to skip `//other phpo codes` if we have error connecting to DB and straight to show my html elements. Is that possible to do it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just out that code in your `try/catch`. Once the exception is thrown execution is handed off to the `catch` portion of the control structure and that portion of code is never reached:

```
 try{
     //connect to DB    

     // If an exception is throw above we never get here

     //other php codes...

 }catch(exception $e){
      echo $e
 }

//My html elements...
<div>....
```

Comment: thanks but I am trying to skip //other php codes after the try and catch codes. +1

Comment: I know. That's what I show in my example. I moved that code *into* the try catch.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to move the // other php code
And you don't want/can't edit the try/catch block, surely the try/catch returns some variable you can test, even if only that $e.

```
try {
    // something like $connected_db should be available
}
catch (exception $e)
{
}

if (!empty($connected_db) AND empty($e)) // one or the other depending on the code above
{
// other php code
}

// my html elements
```